# How to download all rpm dependencies independent from platform running

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux, yum, rpm

How to download all rpm (not installed) dependencies without rpm itself. Independent from platform running - download dependency if its installed anyway.

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/1/yumdownloader

Answer (score 1):

Just use yum with the download only plugin to only download all the needed dependencies (you must have the "yum-plugin-downloadonly" package installed beforehand) in a local directory like so:

```
#yum install --downloadonly --downloaddir=/path/to/store/rpm_and_deps package_you_want.rpm
```

I have to point out that you need a local repo configured which contains all the dependencies or have access to the internet and a valid online repo.

Comment: thanks for your answer unfortunately this command not only downloads dependencies but also updates Linux packages before doing so while I am looking for the solution which would be linux independent and download dependency even if it is installed